# IDLE 2.7.5+ doesn't work in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, idle-python

Recently, after upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 I can't open .py files in IDLE 2.7. When I click in "File - Recent Files - file.py" I get an empty window. In this window the code is absent and I can't close it normally, just via "pkill idle" in the terminal.

When I try to open the file.py via terminal with idle:

```
idle path_to_file/file.py
```

I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1536, in main
    if flist.open(filename) is None:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/FileList.py", line 36, in open
    return self.EditorWindow(self, filename, key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 131, in __init__
    EditorWindow.__init__(self, *args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/EditorWindow.py", line 323, in __init__
    io.loadfile(filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 258, in loadfile
    chars = self.decode(chars)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 296, in decode
    enc = coding_spec(chars)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py", line 129, in coding_spec
    for line in lst:
NameError: global name 'lst' is not defined
```

I need help, I can't work with my .py files in IDLE !!!

Thanks and Best wishes to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=725995). It's fixed in idle 2.7.6, but you can easily(*) fix it yourself.

Open the file /usr/lib/python/idelib/IOBinding.py as root with your favorite editor:

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/IOBinding.py
```

Go to line 128 and change:

```
str = str.split("\n", 2)[:2]
```

to:

```
lst = str.split("\n", 2)[:2]
```

and save the file.

(*) Easily if you are a python programmer.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It works !. How I mark this topic as solved?